# href tag not working. css style interfering?

Tags: html, css

I'm relatively new to HTML (only a few weeks now), and I'm stuck.  The "about" section on my page doesn't seem to be clickable and won't bring me to the linked page.  The confusing thing is that the link appears to be clickable since the floating hand icon appears when hovering over the link.  I can right-click and open the link in a new tab.  If I delete the css and try the link without the formatting, it is also valid.

I'm confused... is the CSS somehow messing with my href tag?

here's the html:

```
<div id="header"> 
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="twelwecol last">
                <div id="navigation"> <!-- Navigation Links -->
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="about.htm">about</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#members">members</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#events">events</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#media">media</a></li>             
                        <li><a href="#social">social</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the code from the "navigation.css" page:

```
#header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 49px;
    color: white;
    background-color: #1b1e25;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 9999;
}
#logo {
    background-image: url('../images/assets/logo.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 80px;
    width: 80px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
}
#navigation {
    padding-top: 2px;
    width: 480px;
    display: block;
    margin: 0px auto;
}
#navigation ul {
    padding:0px;
    margin: auto;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
#navigation ul li {
    display:inline;
    float:left;
    list-style:none;
    padding: 13px 20px 13px 20px;
}
#navigation ul li {
    display:inline;
    float:left;
    list-style:none;
    padding: 13px 20px 13px 20px;
}
#navigation ul li a {
    color: gray;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family:'Scada', sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
}
#navigation ul li a:hover {
    color: white;
}
.current {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #cb1c1c;
    color: white;
}
#contact {
    padding-top: 12px;
    float: right;
    position: relative;
}
#contact a {
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 9px;
    color: gray;
    padding: 11px;
}
#contact a:hover {
    color: white;
    border: #333333 1px solid;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Could someone please tell me what is going on here? Any help would be most appreciated!

Comment: Well, as you can see in this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kUWL9/), you code is working right. So is this realy all the code or could there be something else? Also, did try an chache refresh of the page?

Comment: Which browser is causing problem?

Comment: Its working fine, please check http://jsfiddle.net/raunakkathuria/g98cB/ about link is clickable but other will not be as they are internal links, may be some javascript if any is preventing it

Comment: What happens after you click on it? Errors, missing page, anything?

Comment: @RaunakKathuria, thanks for the suggestion - I found some javascript for a scroll command that was interfering.  I'm just learning, so javascript is way above my head at the moment... I just took out code and my link works fine now.  No fancy scrolling, but at least my page is functioning.  Thanks for the help everyone.

Comment: Just some comments: learn the terminology. `href` is an attribute, not a tag. The hand is a cursor, not an icon. And "navigation.css" is a stylesheet, not a page. Things like those matter when you're discussing problems with others.

Comment: @MrLister Thanks for the constructive criticism.  Clearly, I'm just a beginner, but I'll definitely take your advice to heart.  Thanks!

Comment: as you were using some jQuery for scrolling effects .. they normally work on links with # because they treat them as anchors so may be that's why you link was not working.

Comment: @Nishant.  This, is exactly what was happening.  So is there a way to link outside the page AND use the jQuery code for scrolling effects on the other links in the menu?  just curious... i'm sure the explanation would make my newbie brain hurt.

Comment: if these links are not anchor tags just remove the # sign from them and add .html like the first link and if these are supposed to be dummy links then just use # and remove the name after it. Hope that helps

Comment: @Nishant.  Thanks for the input.  The other links are supposed to have anchor tags... it was the first link that was the issue.  For some reason, with the jQuery scroll effects applied to the anchor tags on the other links, the first link wouldn't go to the "about" page.

Answer (score 1):

it appears clickable because it is contained within the `a` tag. When you link something your `href` needs to have a proper extension. Are you sure youre using `.htm` and not `html`?

furthermore  CSS affects Style (css= cascading style sheet) it wont affect html (or any other) functions like the href function.

try changing your href to `href="about.html"`